# Visual Studio 2015 crashes on an IF statement

Tags: visual-studio-2015

[Seems to be a bug]

I'm getting a really weird behavior on Visual Studio 2015.
Every time I have a const inside a method in a controller and try to use an IF statement, my VS 2015 crashes.

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        if() //<-crashes when I try to add this line

        const string filename = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

Has anyone faced this issue as well?
[image: Pic with the code]

Comment: 2015 is still in `Preview` - which is another word for `buggy`.  Contact MS about it.

Comment: @icemanind True, but VS may not crash on this. Rui Lima, you should [file a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) if none already exists.

Comment: @icemanind Well... I know that, but I can't add the condition, VS2015 crashes before I can add anything inside the if(). Did you try this code? Does it crashes to you too?

Comment: @Dan-o I wanted to know if this is only on my machine before I contact MS. Because seems to be a very very lame bug. If filename is a variable works fine only when it's a const it crashes

Comment: I can reproduce the exact same behaviour, @Rui. Crahses, too :(

Comment: It's beta software... what did you expect would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Visual Studio 2015 Preview.
Thanks for the comments

Comment: I can also get VS 2015 to crash every time I type class="" into a div that is enclosed in another div. Have reproduced it at least 5 times!

Comment: @nicoladeep I can't reproduce that issue. What are you using, asp.net forms, razor or simple html?

Comment: hi Rui, it was Razor. i don't have the code right now but can post/send to you when I get home if you want.